# Google Analytics goal/segmenting set up to track traffic from a single website/URL?

Tags: google-analytics

How can I set up Google Analytics goal to track traffic from a single website and track whether the user ends up on specific pages (as in, track how they move through the funnel/website) as well if they convert to a subscriber (I can put that tracking code on a signup / thank you page).

But I am concerned about traffic only from a single domain, as a specific and unique measuring statistic, in addition to overall traffic tracking, obviously.

I can't figure it out for the life of me....

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The filtering would not be a goal setting. Set up, either:

A custom segment that filters users based on the referrer / hostname / whatever you need. It sounds like you are looking to filter on the referrer or referrerPath. Then set up the goal and when you report, change the segment

Or set up a separate view that filters for traffic based on the criteria above. That view can then have the goal, inclusive funnels, set up.

Both methods have drawbacks, the second method is cleaner if that goal is something you plan on reporting on for the foreseeable future.